# A running toilet that stops itself

Tags: toilet

I have a toilet that will start running as if the flapper is bad. (I’m confident it is not. I’ve replaced it twice.) It doesn’t drain much, just enough to trigger a fill every 20 - 30 minutes.

The strange thing is the tank only drains slightly and then stops. If I turn the water off it will only drain approximately 1/4 to 3/8’s of an inch and then stop draining completely. I can leave the water turned off for two weeks and it will never go below that level. I’m thinking if it were a bad seal it would drain completely after that time.

Is it a crack in the tank? I’ve just about had it and ready to replace the toilet. It’s approximately 20 years old.

Comment: have a good look at every component at the water level where the draining stops ..... there may be a small hole that allows the water to drain from the tank ...... when the water drops below the hole, then the draining stops

Comment: @jimmy fix-it, make this comment an answer I have seen the siphon effect several times in the past the first time really had me scratching my head.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it: As Ed said, make this an answer. Answers should never be relegated to comments.

Comment: As others have said, something is siphoning the water out.  This is often because the tube into the overflow pipe is too long -- it should end above water level in the tank.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it - I invite you to post your comment as an answer and then I will delete mine.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it Hopefully I posted the answer correctly. I’m not the best at StackExchange (or fixing toilets apparently, lol).

Comment: I had a flapper that decided that occasionally it would not fall symmetrically over the flush hole. Fixed it by cutting a slot in a short piece of black neoprene(?) cork, and putting it on one side of the connection between flapper and overflow tube, so the flapper could no longer wander into the wrong position. Fixed symptoms very much like you describe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the fill hose/tube (the hose/tube that runs from the fill valve to the overflow tube) is *inserted into*, rather than clipped above and aiming into, the overflow pipe, siphon action will lower the water level in the tank down to the distance the fill hose/tube is inserted.

Ensure the fill hose/tube is not inside of the overflow pipe below the normal water level.

Comment: Yes!  I have seen this exact problem.

Comment: I will have to check this. That’s a good idea. Reading through the tips here (and with the water turned off) I filled the tank with a pitcher to the top of the overflow tube. In the last few days the water only dropped a fraction of an inch. Almost unmeasurable.

Comment: I cut about 2 inches off of the fill hose. So far so good! I think this was it!

Comment: So cool, I've never thought about that. Thinking back I have seen the refill tube actually inserted in the overflow a couple times. Great answer!

Answer (score 16):

Maybe there is a small crack or leak near the top of the toilet tank overflow tube. See diagram below at red arrow.

[image]

<sup>*(Picture Source: https://titanzplumbing.com/does-your-toilet-randomly-start-running/)*</sup>

Answer (score 11):

Clearly the flapper - and just as importantly, the bottom of the tank where the flapper sits - is just fine. Otherwise you would have the toilet eventually empty when the incoming water is turned off.

You have some sort of problem with the **fill valve** and/or the **overflow pipe**. This (a) deliberately feeds some water normally into the toilet after the flapper has closed and (b) if the fill valve were to fail open (not a good thing as it would waste a lot of water very quickly), it would let the water drain down the sewer instead of overlowing the tank onto your bathroom floor.

A 20 year old toilet is old enough that the fill valve and other parts can start to fail. But new enough that standard replacements should work just fine (as opposed to 40 year-old 3.5 gallon toilets). There are plenty of choices (Fluidmaster, Danco, etc.) and the whole kit runs typically $10 to $25 - a lot less than a new toilet. I would avoid the old ball float styles - even if your existing toilet uses one there is no reason to stick with that - the new types are, in my opinion, much better.

Comment: In principle, the flapper could be damaged in a way that only makes it leak if there's high enough pressure above it, and the reduced depth after it's leaked a little means that the pressure is no longer high enough to cause further leaking. That seems very unlikely but it is physically possible, so your first paragraph isn't _quite_ true. The asker says they've replaced the flapper twice, so I agree we can be confident that the flapper isn't the problem.

Comment: It is probably worth buying a kit which includes parts such as the bolts and bushings between the tank and bowl as well as the internal components. Take the old throne apart, give it a good cleaning, replace everything but the porcelain with new components and you'll have ruled out any broken components. I think most "kits" come with those but watch for ones which only include subassemblies.

Answer (score 5):

You probably have a crack in the overflow, the little tube that terminates just above the water line.

You may have to deform it a little by squeezing it for it to become apparent.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Jimmy Fix-It’s suggestion solved the problem. Who ever installed the new float and filler years ago, did not trim the fill hose properly and it was creating a siphon effect.

Thank you Jimmy!